# Socket.IO clients to receive offline messages when coming back

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, offline

#### Environment:

Nodejs+Socketio

#### Problem:

1. client A and client B both connect to server;
2. client B is offline;
3. client A sends a message to client B(client B still offline);
4. client B connect to server again;
5. [**Problem**] client B can't receive the message from A;

#### Server Code

```
var clients = {};
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('online', function (data) {
    if (!clients[data.username]) {
        clients[data.username] = socket;
    }
    io.sockets.emit('message',  data.user + 'online now');
});
socket.on('say', function (data) {
    if (data.to == 'all') {
        io.sockets.emit('message', data.message);
    } else { //to specific client
        clients[data.to].emit('message', data.message);
    }
});
});
```

#### Description

client B connected to server at one place first.During the period of client B's offline, client A sent messages to client B. Then client B connect to server at another place again,  and client B needs to receive those message from client A.  How to make it work?

Comment: IMO there is no way only with sockets to achive this, for this you have to check state of the client B and save the offline messages to DB or to some socket variable, then push it back to client B when online

Comment: Thanks for your comments, any idea about how to check the state of the client B?How do I know whether the client B is online or offline?

Comment: from `socket.on('disconnect', function(){})`

Comment: Post your client side code please.

Comment: Thanks Shawn,Ravi is right that there should be DB to store the offline messages  corresponding to the specific client.

Comment: i want to build a similar private messaging... can you provide me with your original code as well, how you managed it when client b was online as well. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The amount of code I would have to write would be fairly large to create a solution if I consider which db and it's config, and client.  You basically have to persist your messages in a database.  As messages come in you would have to write to your conversation object (or whatever is representing the chat messages between clients).

```
socket.on('say', function (data) {
    // pseudo code to save conversation
    // var conversation = db.getConversation();
    // conversation.addMessage(data.message);
    // conversation.save();
    if (data.to == 'all') {
        io.sockets.emit('message', data.message);
    } else { //to specific client
        clients[data.to].emit('message', data.message);
    }
});
```

Then you would have to get all messages from the database when a client joins.

```
socket.on('online', function (data) {
    if (!clients[data.username]) {
        clients[data.username] = socket;
    }
    // pseudo code to get messages and display to user on first load
    // var conversation = db.getConversation();
    // var messages = conversation.getLast10Messages();
    // messages.forEach(function(message) { 
    //     clients[data.username].emit('message', message);
    // });
    io.sockets.emit('message',  data.user + 'online now');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

use message queue like RabbitMQ. whenever a message comes from socket write to receiver's queue and when the receiver joins he will pick it from the queue.

Comment: It won't work with multiple clients subscribing to one topic, because message will be dequeued for first client and rest of the offline client won't receive any message.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a unique id as username to every user ,  save it at the server side, or use username, you also have client id(socket id), then save them in an object, now for every user you have an object that contains (username or unique id ) and socket id, now its easy to save messages when user is offline and then send it to user.
Before emitting every event, you can search for socket id in the connected sockets object of socket.if socket id exists, you can emit, else , you still have username, and you can save messages in database by username.

Remember that, you must send receiver object info(username or unique id , and socket id) in every emitting from the client

Comment: This was nice answer. I have an extra question on another topic. Should I save every message in the database (for the purpose of keeping message history) first and then emit the message to respective user or use any broker to keep sending time lower ? In traditional messaging app I don't know which flow is used.